# With left menu I have problems with pages layout

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

Could you please look at layout of the Bootstrap 4.1 page:
http://demo2.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/admin/warehouses/2/edit
It is under credentials  user: admin@demo.com pass: 111111

I have created a left side menu (it must be hidden on small device).
But with this menu there are some features I would like to fix :

1) I need page content (blue border) to be centered and it is ruled by styles :

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 2px dotted red;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#page-wrapper {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Looks like the reason is in props display and align-items of wrapper class, but when I tried to modify these values
the left menu stopped working

2) Listing http://demo2.nilov-sergey-demo-apps.tk/admin/clients must be with horizontal scrolling,but instead scrolling of table with data with syntax

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div id="get-client-dt-listing-table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
           ....
        </div>
    </div>
```

the entire page has horizontal scrolling by mouse scroll.

How to fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set the width of `main` to this:

```
width: calc(100% - 265px);
```

265px = 250px of navbar width + 15px margin right of navbar

and the width of `page-wrapper` to this:

```
width: calc(100% - 20px)!important;
```

20px = 10px margin-left + 10px margin-right

and the 2) should work

For the 1) you should set a max-width to the page-wraper and margin: auto; to be centered. I suggest you to set a class for this page or in an outer container and set the style like this:

```
.warehouses #pagewrapper {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

to avoid impact on the other pages.